# Android AWS S3 library - Synchronous upload

Tags: android, amazon-s3

We are using Android S3 library for uploading content. Now we are upgrading our app to target SDK version 26.

In one of our service, we are storing all the request in DB and upload the content when the job is posted. We made sure that the internet is available.

But we call below line to upload the file,

```
final TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(getS3Client(), ApplicationNekt.getContext());
final TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(uploadConfig[0], uploadConfig[1], file);
```

This internally call startService() to start their internal TransferService.

```
        S3ClientReference.put(id, s3);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, TransferService.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_BUNDLE_TRANSFER_ID, id);
        intent.putExtra(TransferService.INTENT_BUNDLE_TRANSFER_UTILITY_OPTIONS,
                        this.transferUtilityOptions);
        appContext.startService(intent);
```

So this crashes our app in Oreo, as background services are not allowed.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Not allowed to start service Intent { act=add_transfer cmp=com.ourapp/com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{62479b u0a200 LAST bg:+1m21s705ms idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
```

Is there any way to start the delivery service synchronously?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/400 Looks like this is an issue for the last 6 months. And recently AWS dev team has updated the status.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/400#issuecomment-423260044 Based on this answer. From s3 library 2.7.0, this crash is fixed. Yet to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For synchronous upload/download there is a separate API in S3client. It uploads and downloads without any service dependency. Refer putObject and getObject in S3 client.

```
    AmazonS3Client sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getCredProvider());
    PutObjectResult result = sS3Client.putObject(bucket, key, file);
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/400#issuecomment-430712072

P.S. From 2.7.x versions, AWS separated out the background service. That is also can be used. 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/400#issuecomment-423260044

Comment: What did you end up doing ? Do you use `Worker` from Android JetPack and start the upload synchronously with the code you posted ? And is it working ?